# Setting AngularJS app configurations after a service has been called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I am using `$urlRouterProvider` service in my `app.config` to define the default routes in my AngularJS application. I define it as follows:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', '/history')
    .otherwise('/history');

$stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        template: '<my-tab></my-tab>',
        onEnter: function(){console.log("enter");}
    })
});
```

My problem is that I want to set these routes after a Boolean variable `flag` is fetched from database using a custom service (databaseService). If the `flag` is `true`, it should be:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', '/history')
    .otherwise('/history');
```

and if `flag` is `false`, it should be:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', '/future')
    .otherwise('/future');
```

How can I achieve this? I am not able to use a custom service in app.config function. Also I can't set configurations in my service because config gets set before a service is loaded. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to change this once at the start of the application you could to the following ([docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)):

```
var routerProvider = null; // reference router for run phase

angular
  .module('app')
  .config(config)
  .factory('databaseService', databaseService)
  .run(run);

config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider'];
run.$inject = ['$urlRouter', 'databaseService'];

function config($urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
  routerProvider = $urlRouterProvider;
}

function databaseService() {
  return {
    getDbFlag: function() {
      // connect to db and fetch data
    }
  };
}

function run($urlRouter, databaseService) {
  databaseService.getDbFlag()
    .then(function (serviceData) {
      // set the route with data from the DB
      routerProvider.otherwise(serviceData.route);

      $urlRouter.sync();
      $urlRouter.listen();
    });
}
```